# Android Loggable can still be observerd on Logcat after setprop

Tags: android, android-logcat, android-log

Before I did any changes, I printed `Log.isLoggable(MYAPP_TAG)` for all levels.

```
I/System.out﹕ MYAPP Loggable Level: [V:false][D:false][I:true][W:true][E:true]
```

And then I did `adb shell setprop log.tag.MYAPP_TAG WARN`.

The `Log.isLoggable(MYAPP_TAG)` message now became

```
I/System.out﹕ MYAPP Loggable Level: [V:false][D:false][I:false][W:true][E:true]
```

However, all log messages (`Log.v`, `Log.d`, etc) can still be observed in Logcat.

```
02-03 13:18:28.050    3284-3284/com.XX V/MYAPP_TAG﹕ onServiceConnected
02-03 13:18:28.050    3284-3284/com.XX D/MYAPP_TAG﹕ onServiceConnected
```

Why is that?

Comment: Are you trying to hide debug during runtime of a deployed app or are you trying to just suppress it while debugging?

Comment: I am trying to suppress it while debugging.

Comment: hmm... wait what's the difference?

Comment: If it is just for you, you can use [filters on logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#filteringOutput).  If you are trying to permanently remove log entries from other people viewing them, you should check out [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018263/android-logging#comment5791618_2019563).

Comment: This is a good answer if you are trying to hide logs in production (release): http://stackoverflow.com/a/2019597/1895218

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to wrap your logs:

```
if (Log.isLoggable("MY_TAG", Log.VERBOSE)) {
        Log.v("MY_TAG", "Here's a log message");
}
```

otherwise android seems to ignore your settings; it seems like the `Log.v, Log.d, etc.` are not checking against the LogLevel.

Comment: It returns "usage: setprop <key> <value>"

Comment: This solution would be pretty verbose with a lot of log messages and add more overhead.  Check out this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018263/android-logging/2019597#2019597