# How do I remove log lines from android?

Tags: java, android, proguard

I tried with

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}
```

as well as

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

My Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile project(':aFileChooser')
    compile project(':balysvMaterial')
    compile project(':bottomSheet')
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vicky.test"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
```

But still i am getting the log lines in log-cat After exporting signed APK.

displaying Log lines Example

```
Log.i(TAG, "name       : " + name);
Log.i(TAG, "gender : " + gender);
```

Is there anything i done wrong... 
please help me.

Comment: Are you sure that APK is not debug build ? Did you actually do release build with release key/password ?

Comment: @Jabbar_Jigariyo I think his build has a problem.  But I personally like [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018263/how-do-i-enable-disable-log-levels-in-android) for controlling logging.  It uses log configurable log levels and is similar to other Java logging frameworks like `log4j`.

Comment: yes it an play-store up-loadable signed apk

Comment: Try this: public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);

Comment: @Vignesh Then I don't think your proguard is being utilized properly. Check that out in your local release build. Add/remove more stuff from proguard and run the release build locally. Check whether it has any effect of your changes or not.

Comment: Can you add your `build.gradle`, please?

Comment: I am using Eclipse for android app building.I think for finding this line you need built.gradle.
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt