# how to enable logger in specific screen of release-build in android?

Tags: android, logging, apk, release-builds

how to enable logger in specific screen of release-build in android?

I Realeased an APK in playstore which is obfuscated apk and Logger are disabled , When customers find some issues in that apk in specific screen. So i want to Enable Logger in that specific screen of release-build.
Is it possible, If Yes how can i acheive..??

**Updated Question:**

Apk release build - Obfuscated by DexGuard

Thanks

Comment: you can use Crashlytics logs: http://try.crashlytics.com/
Crashlytics will show all the logs when an fetal or non fetal exception is occurred in crashlytics dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Log.i. Information logs are always showed to users. [See more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2019563/3379437).
If you used ProGuard to remove all logs from your application you should remove clearing of `public static int i(...);` from rules.

If it wasn't enough flexibility try [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber)
And [setup ReleaseTree](https://caster.io/episodes/episode-14-logging-with-timber/) for your release versions

Comment: yep, that could be a problem. I've never used that commercial obfuscation..

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to enable logger in release builds. Instead of that you can use this [lib](https://github.com/inaka/galgo) to print log on your screen.

Another solution you can find an example of it [here](https://github.com/ArFe/Android/tree/master/OnScreenLog). It's really simple, just add a class OnScreenLog to your project

Comment: its nice.., but i dont want to print on screen, i need data in txt file format to identify issue of that application.

Comment: So just write data on file. First create a text file on public directory and then append data on that file. You can ask client to send you file by giving him full path of file.