# How can I enable verbose debug on Cast SDK3 and CAF receiver?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk, caf-receiver-sdk

I'm converting to CAF receiver and Cast SDK 3. I'm having some issues with sending messages from the CAF receiver to the sender. I think the CAF part is working but to make sure I would like to enable verbose logs. How can I do that for both the sender (Android) and receiver?

Thanks.

Comment: You may try the answer in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2019597/8342742). Try to do an `int` named `loglevel` and define base on the log level. Refer to the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) for an in depth details about logs. Also found Android TV debugging from the [Google cast documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_tv).

Comment: That seems to be for generic Android debugging. I'm already logging on Android, I want to enable logging on the Cast SDK. V2 of the SDK had a log level option but I can't find it on V3. As far as the receiver end or Android TV, I'm already going into the log console, but I don't know how to enable verbose logging. I already had that on the V2 receiver but the V3 CAF receiver doesn't seem to have that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that's late but for others - on receiver side it's done this way:

`castContext.setLoggerLevel(cast.framework.LoggerLevel.DEBUG);`

Comment: I don't see that method on the documentation but I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like the method call does exist. Didn't see much change on the logs.

Comment: It's described here https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.CastReceiverContext#setLoggerLevel

Comment: Thanks, no idea why I didn't see it before.