# Implementation of interface from library does not work - what am i missing?

Tags: java, kotlin, interface

I have been struggling with this for quite some time now:

I am trying to write a rather small Android app in Kotlin. Its purpose is to receive Data from a Bluetooth device. The vendor of the device has made an Android API for that purpose. The idea of the API is the following:

After establishing a connection and starting data acquisition, the device sends the data back to the Android device. Then, the third party library (API) is supposed to call a method, which can be implemented into a class via an interface.

I got everything to the point where the connection works and the data acquisition runs. I also know from the log that the Android device receives data, but **the functions that I have implemented over the interface do not get called**.

I implemented the interface like so:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
class AndroidBluetoothController(
    private val context: Context
) : BluetoothController, OnDataAvailable {
```

Android Studio automatically added the implemented functions for me and I implemented them as well:

```
override fun onDataAvailable(frame: Parcelable?) {
    Log.i("FRAME",frame.toString())
}
override fun onDataLost(p0: String?, p1: Int) {
    Log.e("onDataLost", p0.toString()+"->"+p1.toString())
}
```

The API seems to work in general, as all other functionalities of it are available, but nothing appears in the logs.

By now, I am out of ideas. Could it be an issue with DI? I am using Dagger-Hilt.

The AndroidBluetoothController is injected like so:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideBluetoothController(@ApplicationContext context: Context): BluetoothController {
        return AndroidBluetoothController(context)
    }

}
```

And then it is called in the Viewmodel:

```
    @HiltViewModel
class BluetoothViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val bluetoothController: BluetoothController
) : ViewModel() {
```

Comment: how is `AndroidBluetoothController` initialized/injected ?

Comment: @sidgate Thanks a lot four your question. I edited the Question!

Comment: Could it be that your Logger is not configured as you expect and the `Log.i(...)` call is working fine but the output is being suppressed because you have not configured the logging system correctly?  I cannot advise on how to configure the logging system (https://stackoverflow.com/q/2018263/1847378 might be a start), but easier: just abuse the log system for a test and switch to `Log.e(..)` perhaps that will immediately show something for you.

Comment: Hi @AndrewL, a very good idea! I tested it with log.e(); unfortunately i still get nothing.

Comment: Does `Log.e(..)` work nearby in your code?  e.g. put something in `provideBluetoothController()` so you know that is being executed